# What does 'that they are' mean?

Tags: meaning

Is is like 'as they are?'

> War is inconceivable without some image, or concept, of the enemy. It
> is the presence of the enemy that gives meaning and justification to
> war. ‘War follows from feelings of hatred’, wrote Carl Schmitt. ‘War
> has its own strategic, tactical, and other rules and points of view,
> but they all presuppose that the political decision has already been
> made as to who the enemy is’. The concept of the enemy is fundamental
> to the moral assessment of war: ‘The basic aim of a nation at war in
> establishing an image of the enemy is to distinguish as sharply as
> possible the act of killing from the act of murder’. However, we need
> to be cautious about thinking of war and the image of the enemy that
> informs it in an abstract and uniform way. Rather, both must be seen
> for the cultural and contingent phenomena that they are. Rather, both
> must be seen for the cultural and contingent phenomena ***that they
> are***.

[The Ethics of War: Shared Problems in Different Traditions](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=Q4geVtqE4c4C&pg=PT297&lpg=PT297&dq=Rather,%20both%20must%20be%20seen%20for%20the%20cultural%20and%20contingent%20phenomena%20that%20they%20are.&source=bl&ots=E2bbgxPLPm&sig=ACfU3U1XN6ZC2wNoqeMGRM0_zY7ZLSzAjw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTxNimwLTqAhUfw4sBHUzmD54Q6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Rather%2C%20both%20must%20be%20seen%20for%20the%20cultural%20and%20contingent%20phenomena%20that%20they%20are.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

One can see war and the image of the enemy as brute facts that exist on their own -- which they are not.

Or as  cultural and contingent phenomena -- which they are.

Yes, the sentence could be paraphrased to use "as they are" instead without change in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, it is a restrictive relative clause:

> Which cultural and contingent phenomena should they be seen as? The ones that, in fact, they are.

But of course that doesn't make a lot of sense pragmatically - everything in the universe is what it is. So the phrase has a pragmatic meaning of

> These are cultural and contingent phenomena, and that's how we should view them.